# If $\|u\| = 2$, $\|v\| = \sqrt3$, and $u \cdot v = 1$, find $\|u + v\|$.

Tags: linear-algebra

First year university linear algebra.

Can the answer can be found using the pythagoras theorem, which yields

$\|u + v\| = 2 + \sqrt3$   after 'square root'-ing each side.

Comment: It does not look right. If we are in a geometric mood, we use the Cosine Law. If we are in an algebraic mood, we use $||x||^2=x\cdot x$, and expand $(u+v)\cdot(u+v)$ in the natural way.

Comment: $$\|u+v\|\le\|u\|+\|v\|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(u + v)(u + v) = \|u+v\|^2$$

But: $$(u + v)(u + v) = \|u\|^2 + u\cdot v + v\cdot u + \|v\|^2 = 4 + 1 + 1 + 3 = 9$$

So: $$\|u+v\| = 3$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$
\|u+v\|^2 = (u + v) \cdot (u + v) = u \cdot u + 2 (u \cdot v) + v \cdot v
$$

Comment: No,no, no, no... You used $\cdot $ instead of $\langle \rangle$.

Comment: :-) jk! ${}{}{}{}$